# Reading a directory

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to solve exercise from K&R; it's about reading directories. This task is system dependent because it uses system calls. In the book example authors say that their example is written for Version 7 and System V UNIX systems and that they used the directory information in the header < sys/dir.h>, which looks like this:

```
#ifndef DIRSIZ
#define DIRSIZ 14
#endif
struct direct {    /* directory entry */
    ino_t d_ino;           /* inode number */
    char d_name[DIRSIZ];   /* long name does not have '\0' */
};
```

On this system they use 'struct direct' combined with 'read' function to retrieve a directory entry, which consist of file name and inode number.

```
.....
struct direct dirbuf;    /* local directory structure */
while(read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)
               == sizeof(dirbuf) {
    .....
}
.....
```

I suppose this works fine on UNIX and Linux systems, but what I want to do is modify this so it works on Windows XP.

Is there some structure in Windows like 'struct direct' so I can use it
with 'read' function and if there is what is the header name where it is
defined?

Or maybe Windows requires completely different approach?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like that in windows. If you want to enumerate a directory in Windows, you must use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx)/[FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx) API.

Comment: Somehow I don't think making a Windows application dependent on a Unix Emulation library is a good design choice for new code. Furthermore, MinGW does nothing to fix this problem. You can't open directory files with MinGW. Cygwin might support some kinds of things like this but MinGW does not.

Comment: Ok, but paleman stated in the question that he is solving exercises from K&R. So I think that Cygwin is very reasonable choice for that. I agree with you that using Cygwin for making a production app wouldn't be such a rewarding idea.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that MinGW wouldn't work here, I've edited my answer to correct that one.

Comment: Thanks for that links, I'm gonna try something with FindFirstFile/FindNextFile functions probably.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works on Linux/Unix only. However if you are just playing around you may use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to build programs on Windows that use this Unix API.

Comment: No I don't want to use Cygwin,I forgot to write that when I was writing first post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator` provides a portable equivalent of Windows FindFirstFile/FindNextFile API and POSIX readdir_r() API. See [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#tutorial).

Note that this is **C++** not plain C.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to note that you are using K&R 1st Edition, from 1978, and not the second edition.  The second edition has different structures, etc, at that point in the book.

That code from the first edition does not work on many Unix-like systems any more.  There are very few Unix machines left with file systems that restrict file names to the 14-character limit, and that code only works on those systems.  Specifically, it does not work on MacOS X (10.6.2) or Solaris (10) or Linux (SuSE Linux Enterprise Edition 10, kernel 2.6.16.60-0.21-smp).  With the test code shown below, the result is:

```
read failed: (21: Is a directory)
```

Current editions of POSIX explicitly permit the implementation to limit what you can do with a file descriptor opened on a directory.  Basically, it can be used in the '`fchdir()`' system calls and maybe a few relatives, but that is all.

To read the contents of the directory, you have to use the [`opendir()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) family of functions, and then [`readdir()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) etc.  The second edition of K&R goes on to use these system calls instead of raw  `open()` and `read()` etc.

All-in-all, it is not dreadfully surprising that code from over 30 years ago doesn't quite work the same as it used to.

---

On Windows, you can either use the POSIX sub-system or an emulation of that such as Cygwin or MingW, and in either case you will need to use the `opendir()` and `readdir()` family of function calls, not direct `open()` and `read()` on the directory file descriptor.

Or you can use the native Windows API that BillyONeal references, [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and relatives.

---

Test code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open(".", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        ssize_t n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n < 0)
        {
            int errnum = errno;
            printf("read failed: (%d: %s)\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
        }
        else
            printf("read OK: %d bytes (%s)\n", (int)n, buffer);
        close(fd);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I was reading that book online once and it was written "2.nd edition" next to the name, I don't have it in paper form yet so I don't know

Comment: Interesting - did what you were looking at use prototypes?  If so, it was 2nd Edn rather than 1st.  But, in my copy of the 1st Edn (p170), there is '`#define DIRSIZ 14 / struct direct { ino_t d_ino; char d_name[DIRSIZ]; };`' (and no mention of `opendir()` etc).  In my copy of the 2nd Edn (marked 'Based on Draft Proposed ANSI C', dated 1988, 1st printing) on p180, there is '`#define NAME_MAX 14 / typedef struct { long ino; char name[NAME_MAX+1]; } Dirent;`' (and a discussion of `opendir()` et al.  Your code looks closer to 1st Edn than second edition to me - hence my commentary.

Comment: @paleman: Then it is 2nd Edition of K&R.  Are you looking more at 'The C Answer Book' (Tondo & Gimpel - http://www.amazon.com/C-Answer-Book-Clovis-Tondo/dp/0131098772)?  If so, then it might contain what you show - I've not got a copy to look at.  Do you have the online URL you can share?

Comment: I just looked and it has both."#define NAME_MAX 14 / typedef struct { long ino; char name[NAME_MAX+1]; } Dirent;" would be portable structure and it has comment /* portable structure entry */, it also has "#define DIRSIZ 14 / struct direct { ino_t d_ino; char d_name[DIRSIZ]; };" which would be directory entry for that specific system.
In the example authors also have written opendir, readdir and closedir.
Only their readdir returns 'Dirent *' instead of 'struct dirent *'.
In the body of readdir they copy information from 'struct direct' to 'static Dirent' and return address od 'Dirent'.

Comment: I don't have and did not read "The C Answer Book".Only online URL I know of doesn't exist anymore, they decided to take it of, probably because of copyrights, sorry.